# Cannot update parse user details - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, heroku, parse-platform

I use below code on AppDelegate.swift to check if a user is logged in in order to change the default view controller.

```
 if let user = PFUser.currentUser()!["username"] {

        print("asldkeu \(user)")
        // Code to execute if user is logged in
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController")

        self.window?.rootViewController = viewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    } else {
        // Default screen you set in info plist.
    }
```

Which works correctly, but the problem is that then I cannot update my online parse user data. Whenever I try to update any data on my Heroku Parse app I get below error code:

> Error Domain=Parse Code=206 "cannot modify user Jpibm8rWyI" UserInfo={code=206, temporary=0, error=cannot modify user Jpibm8rWyI, NSLocalizedDescription=cannot modify user

I am using below code to update parse data:

```
if let games = PFUser.currentUser()?["gamesWon"]! {
            print("asldkeu server: \(games as! Int)")

            gamesWon = (games as! Int) + 1
                print("asldkeu update: \(gamesWon)")
            }


            PFUser.currentUser()?["gamesWon"] = gamesWon

            do {
                try PFUser.currentUser()!.save()
            } catch {
                print("asldkeu \(error)")
            }}
```

And if I use PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground() I don't get an error, but the data isn't saved.

Any help how this can be solved?

Comment: Someone? Something?

Comment: Are you sure, you are logged in correctly? You can only change your own user

Comment: The user is correctly logged in.

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? I'm having the same issue, I posted to parse-server github. I'm not getting any server errors though.

Comment: I have managed to update the data only when I changed the ACL on Public read + write. This is the only method that I have found that made my parse data to get updated. Also made a new class on parse for storing my data and I don't put them on Users.

Answer (score 0):

You are not force unwrapping the user.

instead of `PFUser.currentUser()?["gamesWon"] = gamesWon`

use

```
PFUser.currentUser()!["gamesWon"] = gamesWon
```

Note that there is a `!` rather than `?`